# execve and pipe issues - how to read last output?

Tags: c, macos, pipe, execve

I am trying to execute following command and reads it's output.

```
/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep 'Serial Number'
```

I have to use `execve` directly (no `popen`). I believe I'm failing at last step, reading output from second child into parent's buffer. I get 'Reading problem' message.

```
char *cmd1[] = {"system_profiler", "SPHardwareDataType", 0};
char *cmd2[] = {"grep", "'Serial Number'", 0};
pid_t pid;
int pipe1[2];
int pipe2[2];
int ret;

pipe(pipe1);

// first child
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
 return;
}

if (pid == 0) {
 close(pipe1[0]); // close read-end
 dup2(pipe1[1], 1); // copy write-end over stdout
 close(pipe1[1]); // close write-end
 execve("/usr/sbin/system_profiler", cmd1, NULL);
 exit(1);
}

pipe(pipe2);

// second child
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
 return;
}

if (pid == 0) {
 // handle connection between first and second child
 close(pipe1[1]); // close write-end
 dup2(pipe1[0], 0); // copy read-end over stdin
 close(pipe1[0]); // close read-end
 // handle connection between second child and parent
 close(pipe2[0]); // close read-end
 dup2(pipe2[1], 1); // copy write-end over stdout
 close(pipe2[1]); // close write-end
 execve("/usr/bin/grep", cmd2, NULL);
 exit(1);
}

close(pipe1[0]);
close(pipe1[1]);
close(pipe2[1]);

ret = read(pipe2[0], buffer, 128);
if (ret <= 0) {
 printf("Reading problem!\n");
 return;
}
buffer[ret] = '\0';
printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: so what is errno when read returns -1?

Comment: no, read returns 0. I checked it now.

Comment: "last step" means you are sure the problem is in the call of `execve`, right?

Comment: No, not 100% sure. I believe I've done other things right?

Comment: I believe `ret` will be zero if you try to read from an empty pipe, so "Reading Problem" should only be printed if the value is less than zero.

Comment: Ok. I will modify that if. Still - what could be the problem with this code?

Comment: I've added checks on each function to see if something fails, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

LOL. Code was correct except my string definition. I had 'String Number', but quotes were problem - I removed them.

Comment: Yup — that was your trouble...I just came up with the same answer and did a refresh before adding my answer and saw that you'd made the diagnosis.  The shell removes the single quotes; the single quotes protect what appears between them from other shell expansion/interpretation.  In your program, you don't need them.  You're running on Mac OS X, aren't you?